# Determine all $\overrightarrow{a}$ for which the estimator is an unbiased estimator for the variance

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, expected-value, variance, parameter-estimation

consider a random variable $X$ and stochastically independent repetitions $X_1,...,X_n$ of $X$.
For each vector $\overrightarrow{a}=(a_1,...,a_n) \in \mathbb{R}^{n} \text{ with } a_i > 0 $ we denote with $T_\overrightarrow{a}$ the estimator 
$$T_\overrightarrow{a} = a_1 . X_1 + a_2 . X_2 + ... + a_n . X_n$$
for the expected value.

**Solution:** (which is provided in the textbook)

$$E(T_\overrightarrow{a})
= E(a_1 .X_1 + a_2 .X_2 + ... + a_n .X_n)   
= a_1 . E(X_1) + a_2 . E(X_2) + ... + a_n . E(X_n)    
= a_1 . E(X) + a_2 . E(X) + ... + a_n . E(X)  
=(a_1 + a_2 + ... + a_n) . E(X)   \\
\Rightarrow \\
E(T_\overrightarrow{a}) =E(X) \Leftrightarrow  a_1 + a_2 + ... + a_n=1   \\
\Rightarrow
$$
The class of the unbiased estimators is therefore the set of all $T_\overrightarrow{a}$ with $a_1 + a_2 + ... + a_n=1$.

---

I know, how to determine all $\overrightarrow{a}$ for which $T_\overrightarrow{a}$ is an unbiased estimator for the expected value $E(X)$ of $X$, but how to do the same for variance $Var(X)$ of $X$? How can the following task be solved like the one provided in the textbook?

---

**The task for which I need help:**

consider a random variable $X$, whose mean value is known  and stochastically independent repetitions $X_1,...,X_n$ of $X$.
For each vector $\overrightarrow{a}=(a_1,...,a_n) \in \mathbb{R}^{n} \text{ with } a_i > 0 $ we denote with $T_\overrightarrow{a}$ the estimator 
$$T_\overrightarrow{a} = a_1 . (X_1-\mu)^2 + a_2 . (X_2-\mu)^2 + ... + a_n . (X_n-\mu)^2$$  for the variance of X.

a) Determine all $\overrightarrow{a}$ for which $T_\overrightarrow{a}$ is an unbiased estimator for the variance $Var(X)$ of $X$.

b) Determine the most effective among the unbiased estimators $T_\overrightarrow{a}$.

**My thoughts**

a) 
**First try:**
$$E(T_\overrightarrow{a})
= E(a_1 . (X_1-\mu)^2 + a_2 . (X_2-\mu)^2 + ... + a_n . (X_n-\mu)^2)     \\
= a_1 . E(X_1-\mu)^2 + a_2 . E(X_2-\mu)^2 + ... + a_n . E(X_n-\mu)^2    \\  
=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i . E(X_i-\mu)^2    \\
\text{da } E(X_i-\mu)^2=\sigma^2 =Var(X) \text{ für alle } i\\  
\Rightarrow \\
E(T_\overrightarrow{a})
=\sigma^2 .\sum_{i=1}^n a_i   \\
\Rightarrow 
Var(X)=  \frac{E(T_\overrightarrow{a})}{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i}   \\
\hat{\sigma}^2=\frac{T_\overrightarrow{a}}{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i}
$$
**Second try:**
$$Var(T_\overrightarrow{a}
) = a_1^2 . Var(X_1-\mu)^2 + a_2^2 . Var(X_2-\mu)^2 + ... + a_n^2 . Var(X_n-\mu)^2     \\ 
 = a_1^2 . Var(X-\mu)^2 + a_2^2 . Var(X-\mu)^2 + ... + a_n^2 . Var(X-\mu)^2     \\
 = (a_1^2 + a_2^2 + ... + a_n^2) . Var(X-\mu)^2   \\
=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2Var(X-\mu)^2=c\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2    \\
$$

**Third try:**
$$Var(T_\overrightarrow{a}
) = a_1^2 . Var(X_1-\mu)^2 + a_2^2 . Var(X_2-\mu)^2 + ... + a_n^2 . Var(X_n-\mu)^2     \\ 
 = a_1^2 . Var(X-\mu)^2 + a_2^2 . Var(X-\mu)^2 + ... + a_n^2 . Var(X-\mu)^2\\
 = (a_1^2 + a_2^2 + ... + a_n^2) . Var(X-\mu)^2   \\
=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2Var(X-\mu)^2=c\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2    \\
$$

for all $i$ and for some constant $c(\ne 0)$.

I was suggested that I should minimize $Var(T)$ to $E(T)=\sigma^2$, but how to do that?

b) I don't know how to solve it

Thanks :-)

Comment: can I conclude that the solution here is also: "The class of the unbiased estimators is therefore the set of all $T_\overrightarrow{a}$ with $a_1 + a_2 + ... + a_n = 1$"?

Answer (score 1):

As the solution given in your textbook, probabily there are other hypothesis that you did not mention, because when you get

$\mathbb{E}[T]=\mu \sum_i a_i$ the class of the unbiased estimators is

$\hat{\mu}=\frac{T}{\sum_i a_i}$

Where it is included also the class of estimators which your textbook refers.

The same thing happens for the unbiased estimator of the Variance ($\sigma^2$). In fact is enough to observe that, for the stated hypothesis,

$\mathbb{E}[(X_i-\mu)^2]=\sigma^2$ for every $i$

So, e.g., with your first attempt, you immediately get

$\mathbb{E}[T]=\sigma^2 \sum_i a_i$ the class of the unbiased estimators is

$\hat{\sigma}^2=\frac{T}{\sum_i a_i}$

To minimize $\mathbb{V}[T]$, under certain but very general regularity condition, the Cramér Rao inequality

Comment: does that mean that the solution is the same for both tasks? do both the variance and the expected value have the same class?

Comment: can I conclude that the solution here is also: "The class of the unbiased estimators is therefore the set of all $T_\overrightarrow{a}$ with $a_1 + a_2 + ... + a_n=1$".